# SendGrid functionality with distribution list email id

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I'm looking for sending email using SendGrid whereas my From email address would be a Team Id or Distribution list. But in the Send grid portal I can only authenticate single mail address. Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up domain authentication, you can configure your "From" address to be from any email on the authenticated domain.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication

If you need to use single sender verification, that process requires that you (or someone acting on your behalf) have access to the address to complete the verification by clicking on the sent link. In the case of a distribution list email address, this in theory should be able to be done by anybody on the distribution list receiving the email, but everyone will see the verification request.

Comment: I'm aware of domain authentication but for some reason I'm not in a position to use that. So I would like to know if I can use distribution list email for single sender authentication.

Comment: Updated the answer. If you need to use single-sender, then you or someone acting on your behalf needs to be a recipient on the address in order to complete the verification. Whether it is a distribution list email or not shouldn't matter, but everyone on the distribution list will see the verification email come through -- that's the tradeoff you make for not using domain authentication.